# PhpShtorm live edit. Редактирование css файлов

Tags: phpstorm

Всем здравствуйте!
Связка не работает - сайт не обновляется и всё тут. Коннект нормальный.
Если делаю тестовый html файл и стили внутри - всё нормально - обновляется на лету, а css - не хочет. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В версии сторма 8.0.2 вроде как работает, но запускается не всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на [известный баг](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11393) который бал недавно исправлен.

Можно попробовать [EAP версию](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. EAP версия вопрос не решила.
P.S. Беру свои слова назад. Оказалось что необходимо заново установить плагин.